# setcontent view not working

Tags: android, achartengine

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v){
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_chart);
            }

        });
```

Hi i have the above code wherein upon clicking a button i am trying to display them activity activity_chart. In that activity i want to display a graph. Here i am calling a method createIntent(). But my problem is that the graph is not getting plotted. Please help i am new to android.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        createIntent();

    }

    public Intent createIntent() 

     {

...

}
```

Am i calling the method right.

Comment: I fail to fully understand your question.
You want to start a new Activity (activity_chart) and then display something?

Comment: I have an activity in which i have some buttons. When i click on that button i go to another activity where i need to draw the graph and when i do press that button i go to the new activity but it is not plotting the graph. Please help. @siggy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new Activity is called with:

`startActivity(new Intent(currentActivity.this, nextActivity.class));`

Then in your new Activities `onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)` method you can call `setContentView(Layout layout);` to set the new Layout.

So if you want to change the Activity when clicking on a Button you have to do the following:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v){
                startActivity(new Intent(currentActivity.this, nextActivity.class));
            }

        });
```

You are currently only changing the layout of the **current** Activity when clicking the button and **not** changing to another Activity.

I hope I understood you correctly. If not then provide me with some more code so I can try to understand what you want to do.