# Why wont my Android button respond when it is clicked?

Tags: android

Sorry for the simple question (im new to android development)

Ive created a button on a layout with the ID of backToMain.

When the button is pressed, I want the button to return to the activity_main layout.

I have wrote the following code:

```
public class Instructions extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.instructions);

        Button returnHome = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backToMain);
        returnHome.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(true);
        returnHome.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I compile and run the game, the button does not do anything. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/backToMain"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:text="@string/home" 
   />

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: you want to change the layout or return back to a previous activity?

Comment: Are you sure the `Button` is registering a click? I would add a `Toast` just to make sure.

Comment: I want the button to return to the previous activity (activity main) ... I have added a toast and it is not displaying the toast

Comment: well setting the content view is not how you return to an activity. you need to use an intent to return to an activity. first find out why the button is not working

Comment: to return to the previous activity you can just `finish();` the current one. But as mentioned. First find why the button is not clicking

Comment: possible duplicate of [setcontent view not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13680418/setcontent-view-not-working)

Comment: @user2983901 - I made another update - have a look :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your listener method should look like this :

```
returnHome.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
              Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
              startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

It works!

Answer (score 0):

If the following code does not work you should post the layout where the Button is so we can see what is going on with your XML.

```
returnHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Log.d("TAG", "-----------Button click-------------");

        Toast.makeText(Instructions.this, "Button click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Instructions.this.finish();

    }

});
```

Comment: Sadly it still does not work... I have added the XML to the question

Comment: What a strange issue. Is anything happening at all? Is the button showing that it's being pressed by changing color or anything?

Comment: The button changes colour, however, I have placed a toast inside the onClick function and nothing is displayed

Comment: Are you including show() in your Toast? Toast.makeText(Instructions.this, "Button click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: Yes, this is my toast ... Toast.makeText(Game.context, "Button is working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: Try using getApplicationContext() in the Toast instead. Do you set any other listeners to this Button anywhere else in your code?